# Вывод значения переменной

Tags: php

Задали такой вопрос мне,как вывести значение переменной вот таким образом.

```
$m = 10;
$k = 'm';
```

Нужно получить значение переменной m через k,как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Вот так можно в PHP:

```
echo $$k;
```

Т.е., если по простому, сначала берется `$k` - результат `m`, применяем префикс `$`, получаем `$m`.

А еще можно сделать так:

```
$foo = 'count';
echo $foo([1, 1, 1]); //выводит 3
```

Т.е. в итоге получается обращение к функции `count`. С конструкциями `empty`, `isset`, `if else` и т.д. - не прокатит.